# Como executar um script PHP mesmo com o navegador fechado

Tags: php, script

Preciso que um script em php seja executado mesmo com o navegador fechado. Há esta possibilidade?

Gostaria de algumas sugestões.

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Você possui um servidor? ja tentou usar cron?

Comment: Existe como usar o `shell_exec` e usar o `nohup`, dessa forma o processo permanecerá ativo. Parece estranho, mas o `qualquercoisa.php` pode chamar `outracoisa.php` (ou ele mesmo, mas ai criasse um loop) e não será interrompido por desconexão. Se isso é ideal é outra historia. hahaahha

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo scripts php em background utilizando linux.

basta colocar

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// CODIGO PHP
```

e colocar seu código php.

Depois você configura o crontab do seu linux para executar seu script em horários e/ou dias determinados.